# Set table name as variable in a view oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view like this:

---

```
create or replace view caritoplam as
    select
        clcard.parentclref,
        CLCARD2.CODE,
        SUM(GNTOTCL.DEBIT - GNTOTCL.CREDIT) AS TOPLAM
    FROM
        LG_001_CLCARD CLCARD,
        LG_001_CLCARD CLCARD2,
        LG_001_01_GNTOTCL GNTOTCL
    WHERE
        GNTOTCL.CARDREF=CLCARD.LOGICALREF 
        AND GNTOTCL.TOTTYP=1
        AND clcard.code not like '61%'
        and clcard.parentclref = clcard2.logicalref
        and clcard.active = 0 
GROUP by CLCARD.parentclref,CLCARD2.CODE
order by clcard.parentclref;
```

How can I set the table name as variable? E.g.:

exp: `LG_ || variable || _CLCARD`

Comment: In a view? At the point you query it (which you can't do - you'd need a pipelined table function that uses dynamic SQL), or when you create the view (which you could do dynamically, or perhaps with substitution variables)?

Comment: i think it must be procedure

Comment: So you want to supply the `001` part of the table name (both tables? what about the `01`?) as part of your query? Having identical tables with different, indexed, names suggests a data model problem really - why don't you have a single table, partitioned if necessary?

Comment: i have many tables

Comment: i have mant table LG_001_CLCARD  , LG_002_CLCARD , LG_003_CLCARD  ext.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to supply the table name - or, in this case, part of the table name - at run time - you can use dynamic SQL. You can hide that in a pipelined table function, where the return type is a table of objects, with both types defined at schema level. For example:

```
create type caritoplam_obj as object (
  parentclref number, -- or whatever your real table data types are
  code varchar2(5),
  toplam number
)
/

create type caritoplam_tab as table of caritoplam_obj
/

create function caritoplam (p_index varchar2)
return caritoplam_tab pipelined as
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_caritoplam_obj caritoplam_obj;
begin
  open l_cursor for 'select caritoplam_obj(clcard.parentclref,
      clcard2.code,
      sum(gntotcl.debit - gntotcl.credit))
    from lg_' || p_index || '_clcard clcard
    join lg_' || p_index || '_clcard clcard2
    on clcard2.logicalref = clcard.parentclref
    join lg_' || p_index || '_01_gntotcl gntotcl
    on gntotcl.cardref=clcard.logicalref 
    where clcard.code not like ''61%''
    and clcard.active = 0 
    and gntotcl.tottyp = 1
    group by clcard.parentclref,clcard2.code
    order by clcard.parentclref';
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_caritoplam_obj;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;
    pipe row (l_caritoplam_obj);
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;
end caritoplam;
/
```

Let's set up some pretend data, since we don't have the real table structures or data to work with:

```
create table LG_001_CLCARD(logicalref number, parentclref number, code varchar2(5), active number);
create table LG_001_01_GNTOTCL(cardref number, tottyp number, credit number, debit number);

insert into LG_001_CLCARD values (2, 1, '231', 0);
insert into LG_001_CLCARD values (1, null, '231', 0);
insert into LG_001_01_GNTOTCL values (2, 1, 25, 100);

create table LG_002_CLCARD(logicalref number, parentclref number, code varchar2(5), active number);
create table LG_002_01_GNTOTCL(cardref number, tottyp number, credit number, debit number);

insert into LG_002_CLCARD values (7, 6, '654', 0);
insert into LG_002_CLCARD values (6, null, '654', 0);
insert into LG_002_01_GNTOTCL values (7, 1, 21, 42);
```

Now you can call the function, using a table collection expression, and passing the variable part of the table name:

```
select * from table(caritoplam('001'));

PARENTCLREF CODE      TOPLAM
----------- ----- ----------
          1 231           75

select * from table(caritoplam('002'));

PARENTCLREF CODE      TOPLAM
----------- ----- ----------
          6 654           21
```

You could also create a parameterised view using a system context, but that's a bit more work and needs additional privileges; and you would end up having to union together lots of almost identical queries - one union branch for each possible table name. Or you could have a view that does all those unions and adds an extra column to each one, and then when you query add a filter on that extra column so you only get the data from the branch you're interested in. Setting up the unions is still going to be painful - though you could generate the view dynamically if you really wanted to go down that route.

Having lots of identical tables sounds like a strange data model; perhaps you're trying to implement something like partitioning without paying for that option.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle does not allow bind variables for table.So you can't merge string to make a table name.